# No breakaway points , No imaginary axis crossing points and No angle of departure

Tags: root-locus

G(s)H(s) = K(s+1)/[s^2(s+2)(s+4)]

According to my calculations there are 4 poles (0,0,-2,-4) and 1 zero (-1) in this system.No of branches 
are 3.The centroid is -1.67 and the angles of asymptote are 60 deg. ,180 deg. & 300 deg.But in this case there is not any breakaway points and Intersection points with Imaginary axis and angle of departure.Therefore I'm hard to complete my root locus due lack of knowledge.There is someone who can fill that gap of knowledge I'll highly appreciate.

This is what I have done so far.
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htFEu.jpg)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Show what you have so far - show your diagram.

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: @Andyaka Am I correctly done so far?

Comment: I believe @chu to be the likely person to make an answer.